# Power on a Linux machine at specific time

Tags: linux, cron, scheduling

I have a Linux laptop and I want to set it up as an alarm clock (used to have it on my Mac years ago).

The problem is if I shutdown my laptop the night before, the alarm will not work.

Is there a way to set up time schedules in Linux when the machine should power on? Or do I have to do this in BIOS/UEFI...somehow?

It should also wake up from sleep or hibernation.

EDIT: The duplicate question talks about waking up the machine from sleep or hibernation. I want to turn it on from a complete shutdown. I know this can be done on Macs.

Comment: You must configure your BIOS for it, whether the BIOS will wake it up or the OS.

Comment: Yes, but Linux can access UEFI shell. So my guess is that it can be configured in the OS itself.

Comment: @jimmij can I reopen my question. The duplicate is not realy what I want.

Comment: You can configure it in the OS if the BIOS lets you.

Comment: @Alko I've just given that as a *possible* duplicate (as I remembered that question) but not hammer a close, a "Community" does, whoever he/she is, and I cannot reopen this now. However, there are few answers about UEFI, e.g. did you try `nvram-wakeup` software?

Comment: @jimmij yea...I closed it, before checking the provided answer in the duplicate

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams how could I check if I can do that on my machine?

Comment: Look in your BIOS configuration.